# Export a dataframe into a xlsx-file with a dropdown column

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, drop-down-menu

I would like to export a Dataframe into a xlsx-file and have one of the column as a dropdown column

Comment: What do you mean by dropdown: and autofilter or a data validation or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xlsxwriter` and from the [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_data_validate.html?highlight=dropdown), it looks like "Example 6" is what you are after.

To apply this to all the cells in that column, after you export the dataframe, loop over the cells in the column you would like to have the dropdowns for and apply data validation to the cells. Something like this:

```
for i in range(1, len(rows)):
    worksheet.data_validation('B' + i, {'validate': 'list',
                                        'source': ['option1', 'option2', 'option3']})
```